# from how many Relocatable files an Elf execution file Built from?

Tags: c, linker, reverse-engineering, elf, reversing

Is there a way I can find from how many Relocatable files an Elf execution file Built from?
And how can I associate a segment with its original Relocatable file?

Thanks in avance.

Comment: my question is clear right?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can find from how many Relocatable files an Elf execution file Built from?

No (at least not in general).

> And how can I associate a segment with its original Relocatable file?

Any trace of the original `ET_REL` file will be *gone* by the time the linker is done linking.

In addition, with section reordering, a single `.o` can be "spread out" all over the final linked binary, and with identical code folding a single segment of the final binary can be associated with *multiple* `.o` files.

I think http://xyproblem.info is also relevant here.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'm trying to build a tool that will do the opposite to the linker operation (you can call it to "unlink" a file) to .c files files complied and linked with gcc. when I checked the symbol table with readelf, I can see symbols of type "FILE" with the name of the originals files (.c), what these symbols are used for according to your answer?